# Consequences of implementing to_int and to_str in Ruby

Tags: ruby, duck-typing

I [have a class](http://github.com/softcraft-development/sprint/blob/master/lib/sprint.rb) which exposes a string value and an int value (a command output and exit code respectively). In addition to exposing them through `to_s` and `to_i`, I'm also using `to_str` and `to_int`, like so:

```
class Status
  def to_s
    @output
  end
  alias :to_str :to_s

  def to_i
    @status.exitstatus
  end
  alias :to_int :to_i
end
```

My idea behind this is to be able to use this object in as many situations as possible. having it coerceable to a string or int increases that usability. For instance, I can concatenate the object with a string:

```
a_string = "Output was: " + results
```

(I wanted to use this as an example of int coercion, but Fixnum.+ doesn't like it, so it doesn't actually work:)

```
an_int = 1 + results
```

Everything I've read so far has said that this is probably a "bad" thing to do. The common theme goes like this: "Use `to_s`/`to_i` when your object can be represented as a string/int, but `to_str`/`to_int` only if your object *is fundamentally* a string/int".

There's no question that my class is not "fundamentally" a string or an int. However
I have some problems with this rule:

1. It makes my class less flexible/usable. For example: I couldn't use String.+ to concatenate the Status output with the other string if I didn't have Status.to_str.
2. It seems to violate the spirit of duck-typing. The user of an object (ie: a method that gets it as a parameter) shouldn't care what that object *is*, it should only care what it can *do*. (In this case, "do" means "can be represented as a string/int".)
3. The arguments for "is fundamentally a string/int" are pretty fuzzy to me. For example, you'll see that `Float.to_int` is mentioned a lot. The story goes that since a floating-point number always has an integer component, `to_int` is a valid method. However, I think this is spurious: a Float is *not* an integer (as it has a non-integer component) and so trying to equate their "typeness" doesn't make much sense. You can legitimately *convert* a Float to an integer (through truncation), but then I can say that I can *convert* my Status to an integer as well (by "truncating" all of the non-exit-code information).

So, my question is: *is there any real (ie: practical) harm* in implementing `to_str` and `to_int`?

---

Update: Jörg W Mittag gave an example that made me think of something. To rephrase the question: is there really a need to have `to_str`/`to_int` when you already have `to_s`/`to_i`? (Besides the fact that particular methods are already expecting `to_str` over `to_s`)

For instance, in Jörg's Array.join example, the array members are converted via to_s while the separator is converted via to_str. But is this really necessary? If Array.join called separator.to_s instead, then you could successfully pass many more objects to it (ex: Integers, Symbols, etc) and gain that much more flexibility. Does Ruby benefit from having this separation?

Answer (score 8):

> It makes my class less flexible/usable. For example: I couldn't use `String#+` to concatenate the Status output with the other string if I didn't have `Status#to_str`.

This is a bad example, because concatenating strings is unidiomatic Ruby. String interpolation is the preferred way:

```
a_string = "Output was: #{results}"
```

And this *just works*™, because string interpolation actually calls `to_s` on the result of the interpolated expression.

> It seems to violate the spirit of duck-typing. The user of an object (ie: a method that gets it as a parameter) shouldn't care what that object *is*, it should only care what it can *do*. (In this case, "do" means "can be represented as a string/int".)

I would argue that "can be represented as a string/int" isn't really behavior. IOW: "what the object can do" is about interesting behavior in a certain context, and "can be represented as a string/int" isn't really interesting behavior.

If you say that "Status IS-A Integer" (which is essentially what `to_int` means), then it follows that you can, for example, do arithmetic with it. But what does it even *mean* to "add 42 to *file not found*"? What is the logarithm of success? What is the square root of failure?

In the above string interpolation example, the interesting behavior is "can be displayed". And that is basically indicated by implementing `#to_s`. Concatenating two strings, OTOH, requires, well, two strings.

> The arguments for "is fundamentally a string/int" are pretty fuzzy to me. For example, you'll see that `Float#to_int` is mentioned a lot. The story goes that since a floating-point number always has an integer component, `to_int` is a valid method. However, I think this is spurious: a Float is *not* an integer (as it has a non-integer component) and so trying to equate their "typeness" doesn't make much sense. You can legitimately *convert* a Float to an integer (through truncation), but then I can say that I can *convert* my Status to an integer as well (by "truncating" all of the non-exit-code information).

Again, this is a rather weak argument, because I actually agree with you: that's wrong.

In German Law, we have a principle which is hard to grasp and un-inituitive, but which I think applies here perfectly. It is called "Keine Gleichheit im Unrecht" (No Equality in Wrongness). It means that the basic right of Equaliy, which is granted in the Constitution, only applies *within* the Law. To put it another way: OJ doesn't make murder legal.

So, just because there is crap code in the Ruby core library (and believe me, there is a *lot*), doesn't mean you get to write crap, too :-)

In this particular case, `Float#to_int` is just plain wrong and shouldn't exist. `Float` *is not* a subtype of `Integer`. At first glance, the opposite seems to be true, i.e. `Integer#to_float` is valid, but actually that's not true, either: in Ruby, `Integer`s have arbitrary precision, but `Float`s have fixed precision. It *would* be valid to implement `Fixnum#to_float`, but that would be a bad idea, since `Integer`s can magically convert from `Fixnum` to `BigInteger` and back, and thus the `#to_float` method would "magically" appear and vanish.

The thing that finally helped *me* understand the difference between `to_x` and `to_xyz` was `Array#join`: it prints out the elements of the array, separated by a separator object. It does this by calling `to_s` on each element of the array and `to_str` on the separator. Once you understand *why* it calls `to_s` on one and `to_str` on the other, you're basically set.

(Although your comments on `Float#to_int` already indicate that you *do* understand.)

---

Side note: for double dispatch in an algebraic context, Ruby actually uses the `#coerce` protocol. So, if you wanted the `1 + a_status` example to work, you would need to implement `Status#coerce`. But, please don't.

Comment: Agreed on string interpolation being a better way in practice; I used string concat simply as an example of something that required to_str. (In fact, in real coding, I avoid concatenation simply because it *doesn't* work with arbitrary objects).

Comment: So why does `Array#join` call `to_s` on one and `to_str` on the other?

Comment: My guess is, the joined items are not supposed to be strings -- it is implicit that what we want to join is their string representation. OTOH the separator is supposed to be a string, not just any object. Writing `[1,2].join(3)` is an error, and using to_str on the separator is the way to detect it.

Answer (score 4):

The spirit of duck-typing certainly wouldn't have someone look up the source code for the Status object to figure out what is getting returned.

Personally I think you should expose the text results and the exit status through two instance methods:

```
class Status

  ...

  def message
    @output
  end

  def exit_status
    @status.exitstatus
  end

end
```

And then use it as follows

```
a_string = "Output was: " + results.message
a_int    = 1 + results.exit_status
```

Which immediately makes sense to anyone reading the code, IMHO.

Comment: I did that in the actual code (see the linked class), but omitted those methods for brevity in the example code I posted here.