# string conversion of $!

Tags: ruby, exception

I am trying to handle an exception caused by this following code:

```
begin
  reader = CSV.open(ARGV[0],col_sep=";") 
rescue
  puts "exception: " + $!
  exit
end
```

Unfortunately I cannot display correctly the message, Ruby does not interpret $! as string and neither seems to be able to convert it correctly:

```
$ ruby.exe fixcsv.rb csvfile
fixcsv.rb:11:in `+': can't convert ArgumentError into String (TypeError)
        from fixcsv.rb:11:in `rescue in <main>'
        from fixcsv.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

I really cannot understand why this happens; the following tutorial displays similar code that obviously takes into account a correct string conversion of $!:
http://ruby.activeventure.com/programmingruby/book/tut_exceptions.html

Has this anything to do with the fact that I did not explicitly set the exception class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would recommend doing what fl00r did (`Exception => e`), you can still use `$!` if you really want to:

```
begin
  reader = CSV.open(ARGV[0],col_sep=";") 
rescue
  puts "exception: " + $!.message
  exit
end
```

Comment: This is unvirtuous, in that you're not being lazy enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
begin
  reader = CSV.open(ARGV[0],col_sep=";") 
rescue Exception => e  
  puts "exception: #{e.message}"
end
```

Comment: You don't need to do `.message` in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to add `.message` to `e`, from @fl00r's example:

```
begin
  reader = CSV.open(ARGV[0],col_sep=";") 
rescue Exception => e  
  puts "exception: #{e}"
end
```

What happens is that Ruby calls `.to_s` on the exception `e`. Exceptions implement `to_s`, they merely don't implement `to_str`, which is what `"exception: " + $!` tried to do.

The difference between `to_s` and `to_str` is that the former means "You can change me into a string, but I'm not like a string at all", whereas the latter means "Not only can you change me into a string, but I'm very much like a string". [Jorg W Mittag's discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718043/consequences-of-implementing-to-int-and-to-str-in-ruby/1719437#1719437) on `to_s` versus `to_str` is well worth reading.