# Why does `Kernel::String` check `to_str` result while `Kernel::Integer` doesn't check `to_int` result?

Tags: ruby

Both `Kernel::Integer` and `Kernel::String` convert the argument by first trying to call the "long" method (`to_int` and `to_str` respectively), then the "short" method (`to_i` and `to_str` respectively). Both methods check the class of the "short" method result and raise an error if needed:

```
[1] pry(main)> class Dummy
[1] pry(main)*   def to_i
[1] pry(main)*     "42"
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)*   def to_s
[1] pry(main)*     42
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)* end;
[2] pry(main)> Integer(Dummy.new)
TypeError: can't convert Dummy to Integer (Dummy#to_i gives String)
from (pry):9:in `Integer'
[3] pry(main)> String(Dummy.new)
TypeError: can't convert Dummy to String (Dummy#to_s gives Fixnum)
```

This behavior seems to be logical, since the "short" methods are supposed to simply give a "representation". On the other hand, the "long" methods are supposed to be implemented only when the object in question is, essentially, an integer or a string ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718043/consequences-of-implementing-to-int-and-to-str-in-ruby/1719437#1719437)).

However, once we implement the "long" methods, the behavior becomes inconsistent:

```
[4] pry(main)> class Dummy
[4] pry(main)*   def to_int
[4] pry(main)*     "42"
[4] pry(main)*   end
[4] pry(main)*   def to_str
[4] pry(main)*     42
[4] pry(main)*   end
[4] pry(main)* end;
[5] pry(main)> Integer(Dummy.new)
=> "42"
[6] pry(main)> String(Dummy.new)
TypeError: can't convert Dummy to String (Dummy#to_str gives Fixnum)
```

Why are the results treated differently?

I'm using ruby 2.1.2, btw:

```
[7] pry(main)> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.1.2"
```

Comment: I get the same results using ruby 2.2.0 (latest version)

Comment: Btw. same results in `1.9.2p0`, `1.9.3p194`, and `2.0.0p195`.

Comment: .. and don't take it too seriously, but on `IronRuby 1.0.0.0`: in both cases `Integer(..)` fails and `String(..)` gives `"#<Dummy:0x00001d6>"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happens when you call `Kernel#Integer`, aka `rb_f_integer`:

1. `rb_f_integer` calls `rb_convert_to_integer`
2. `rb_convert_to_integer` calls `convert_type(val, "Integer", "to_int", FALSE)`
3. `convert_type` returns `val.to_int` regardless of whether or not it is actually an integer.
4. The important part of `rb_convert_to_integer` is this:

   ```
   tmp = convert_type(val, "Integer", "to_int", FALSE);
   if (NIL_P(tmp)) { // checks if val.to_int is nil. this is the line that causes this
       return rb_to_integer(val, "to_i");
   }
   return tmp;
   ```

So, it checks the return value of `to_int` to see whether it is nil or not, rather than whether or not it is an integer. The line that I commented in that code is the one that causes this bug. The type of the result of `to_i` is checked in the call to `rb_to_integer` above (if the result of `to_int` is nil or the `to_int` isn't defined), however the type of the result of `to_int` is never checked.
An interesting consequence of this:

```
class X
  def to_int
    nil
  end

  def to_i
    42
  end
end

class Y
  def to_int
    false
  end

  def to_i
    42
  end
end

p Integer(X.new) #=> 42
p Integer(Y.new) #=> false
```